# How to rerun same api if response is not 200

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, postman, postman-pre-request-script

in automation postman script, how to rerun the same api if the response is 500 instead of 200, till api's response is other than 500.

```
pm.test("Status code should be 200 on invalid user", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200); 
});
```

Comment: If with same data sometimes it's 500, sometimes it's 200, then first fix your server

Comment: @Justinas server is fine because is happens rarely 1 out of 96 runs, but i have to changes in this script only, if other error come it this same api should again run.